# Removing extra commas from csv file in perl

Tags: perl, csv

I have a multiple CSV files each with a different amount of entries each with roughly 300 lines each.

The first line in each file is the Data labels

```
Person_id, person_name, person_email, person_address, person_recruitmentID, person_comments... etc
```

The Rest of the lines in each file contain the data

```
"0001", "bailey", "123 fake, street", "bailey@mail.com", "0001", "this guy doesnt know how to get rid of, commas!"... etc
```

I want to get rid of commas that are in between quotation marks.
I'm currently going through the Text::CSV documentation but its a slow process.

Comment: Why? This sounds awfully like you think they interfere with the CSV parsing process, but as long as they are inside quoted strings they won't cause a problem unless you are attempting to use a simple "split on comma" parsing technique.  I smell an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Tell us why you want to do this.

Comment: Yes i am splitting on comma, after the data is parsed each line is put into a hash where the Keys are the data from the first line, and the Values are the corresponding data from every other line E.G. "   hash = ( person_id => '0001', person_name =>"bailey" etc...)

Comment: You already have a really nice CSV parser package that will handle all the gory details of successfully parsing CSV, including dealing with quoted strings that contain commas.  Why are you not using it?  What you are doing is similar to being given a turkey and a nice sharp carving set, but deciding to use a sledgehammer to smash the turkey and pick off the meat with your bare hands.

Comment: I don't know how to use the CSV parser, im still reading the documentation and i know it could be done with regex but i dont know much regex.
i dont want to smash my turkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good CSV parser will have no trouble with this since commas are inside the quoted fields, so you can simply parse the file with it.

A really nice module is [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ehmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.34/CSV_XS.pm), which is loaded by default when you use the wrapper [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eishigaki/Text-CSV-1.95/lib/Text/CSV.pm).  The only thing to address in your data is the spaces between fields since they aren't in CSV specs, so I use the option for that in the example below.

If you indeed must remove commas for further work do that as the parser hands you lines.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Text::CSV;

my $file = 'commas_in_fields.csv';

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1, allow_whitespace => 1 } ) 
    or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag (); 

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my @headers = @{ $csv->getline($fh) };   # if there is a separate header line

while (my $line = $csv->getline($fh)) {  # returns arrayref
    tr/,//d for @$line;                  # delete commas from each field
    say "@$line";
}
```

This uses `tr` on `$_` in the `for` loop, thus changing the elements of the array iterated over themselves, for conciseness.

---

I'd like to repeat and emphasize what others have explained: do not parse CSV by hand, since trouble may await; use a library.  This is akin to parsing XML and similar formats: no regex please, but libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Let's get this out of the way: ***you cannot read a CSV by just splitting on commas***. You've just demonstrated why; commas might be escaped or inside quotes. Those commas are totally valid, they're part of the data. Discarding them mangles the data in the CSV.

For this reason, and others, CSV files must be read using a CSV parsing library. To find which commas are data and which commas are structural also requires parsing the CSV using a CSV parsing library. So you won't be saving yourself any time by trying to remove the commas from inside quotes. Instead you'll give yourself more work while mangling the data. You'll have to use a CSV parsing library.

[Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) is a very good, very fast CSV parsing library. It has a ton of features, most of which you do not need. Fortunately [it has examples for doing most common actions](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS#EXAMPLES).

For example, here's how you read and print each row from a file called `file.csv`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use v5.10;   # for `say`

use Text::CSV_XS;

# Open the file.
open my $fh, "<", "file.csv";

# Create a new Text::CSV_XS object.
# allow_whitespace allows there to be whitespace between the fields
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
    allow_whitespace => 1
});

# Read in the header line so it's not counted as data.
# Then you can use $csv->getline_hr() to read each row in as a hash.
$csv->header($fh);

# Read each row.
while( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) {
    # Do whatever you want with the list of cells in $row.
    # This prints them separated by semicolons.
    say join "; ", @$row;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, okay i will not try to remove the commas