# how to remove leading and trailing spaces for specific field in the string in csv file by using regular expression

Tags: perl

Here we go input:

```
X,XXXXX,XXXXXX,  YYYYYY ,TTTTTTT,XXXXXXX,XXXXX  XXXX
Y,YYYYY,YYYYYY,YYY, XXXXXXX    ,TTTTTT,XX XXXX,XX
```

I tried regex: `s/\s//g`  But this substitute will replaces ALL whitespace ANYWHERE within the string.

Please suggest the regex which will only trim and trail the specific field in the whole string??

expected output is:

```
X,XXXXX,XXXXXX,YYYYYY,TTTTTTT,XXXXXXX,XXXXX  XXXX
Y,YYYYY,YYYYYY,YYY,XXXXXXX,TTTTTT,XX XXXX,XX
```

Removing the spaces before and after for that specific field. And it will not disturb the other fields which already having the spaces in it.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Your "_expected output_" completely disagrees with your description

Answer (score 1):

**Note**   This relates to strings more or less as shown, **with strictly no commas inside fields**.

If the problem relates to a general CSV file, please do not even consider regex. Use a module to parse the file and pick fields that you want. Here is the most [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544851/4653379) that comes to mind (where you *don't* want `allow_whitespace` for your purpose). There are many more, please search.

---

Capture all fields, with spaces, as non-comma chars

```
my @m = $string =~ /([^,]+)/g;
```

then clean up what you want and join them back

```
$m[2] =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
$string = join '', @m;
```

Note: it is faster to remove spaces separately, `s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//;`

---

Or, for strings without multiple words in trimmed fields

```
perl -Mstrict -wE'
    $_ = q( xxx ,   yyy ,hey,zz ,  aaa); say;
    my $N = 2;
    my $c; 
    s/(\s*([^, ]+)\s*)/++$c==$N ? $2 : $1/eg; say
'
```

prints

```
 xxx ,   yyy ,hey,zz  ,  aaa
 xxx ,yyy,hey,zz  ,  aaa
```

---

Or, if strings may have multiple words in fields

```
perl -Mstrict -wE'
    $_ = q( xxx ,   yyy more ,hey,zz oo ,  aaa); say;
    my $N = 2;
    my $c; 
    s/(\s*( (?:[^,]+)?[^, ] )\s*)/++$c==2 ? $2 : $1/gex; say
'
```

These work for all `$N` from `1..5`

Comment: That regex is inadequate to split csv fields

Comment: @ysth  Um ... of course -- I am considering OP-style strings, not a CSV file in general.  Otherwise regex just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ysth Right, thank you ... they did say "CSV file" ... sigh

Comment: Hi zdim..thanks for answer.Can u please explain the regex s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; ?

Comment: @CodeSeeker The first of these two statements finds all consecutive spaces (`\s+`) at the beginning of the string (`/^../`) and substitutes nothing for them `s/...//`) -- so it removes them.  The second one finds all consecutive spaces at the end of the string (`$` in regex) and removes them.

Answer (score 0):

So I have two possible answers. One uses `split` and is fine AS LONG as your CSV file is 'basic' - no quoted commas/linefeeds etc.

That covers most of them though, so  I would recommend them as a good starting point.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;


while ( <DATA> ) {    
   my @row = split /,/;
   s/^\s+// for @row;
   s/\s+$// for @row; 
   print join (",", @row),"\n";
}

__DATA__
X,XXXXX,XXXXXX,  YYYYYY ,TTTTTTT,XXXXXXX,XXXXX  XXXX
Y,YYYYY,YYYYYY,YYY, XXXXXXX    ,TTTTTT,XX XXXX,XX
```

If it's anything slightly more complicated though, it's time to break out `Text::CSV`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV; 

my $csv = Text::CSV -> new (); 

while ( my $row = $csv -> getline ( \*DATA ) )  {    
   s/^\s+// for @$row;
   s/\s+$// for @$row; 
   print join (",", @$row),"\n";
}


__DATA__
X,XXXXX,XXXXXX,  YYYYYY ,TTTTTTT,XXXXXXX,XXXXX  XXXX
Y,YYYYY,YYYYYY,YYY, XXXXXXX    ,TTTTTT,XX XXXX,XX
```

With `Text::CSV` you'll either have to feed it `STDIN` or open the file to your CSV file. With `split` you can use `<>`.

Neither is really a 'regex' solution though, as that's IMO entirely the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks Sobrique...its really helpful. But one more challenge I have is  the input data ended with comas for example
X,XXXXX,XXXXXX,  YYYYYY ,TTTTTTT,XXXXXXX,XXXXX  XXXX,,,,,,,,
Y,YYYYY,YYYYYY,YYY, XXXXXXX    ,TTTTTT,XX XXXX,XX,,,,,,,,,,,
I just want to remove the trailing and leading space..with splitting and joining back to a row not exactly giving the output what I am expecting for. I tried to add space at the end of the input string. Please suggest If you have better idea to resole this