# HTTP PUT Request with separate values in csv

Tags: perl, csv, parsing, hash

I want to compare values **separate** in csv. In this code example I **compare hashes**, [Compare values in csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629281/compare-values-in-csv-files) but for my PUT and POST request **I need separate values**.

**output1.csv** (name, ip) - Primary system

```
Test1, 10.56.7.13
Test2, 10.56.4.14
Test3, 10.56.5.15
```

**output2.csv** (id,name,ip) - Secondary system

```
1234,Test1, 10.56.7.13
1235,Test2, 10.56.4.10
```

My result should be:

- do nothing with Test1 (because it is already in System 2)
- update Test2 (because now I have a different ip address)
- add Test3, because I do not have it in the secondary System.

  ```
   say "UPDATE need be done for $second{$name}";
        #Now I want to make PUT (Update) request for these devices in secondary systen. 


  open ( my $input_1, '<', 'output1.csv' ) or die $!;
  while ( <$input_1> ) {
   chomp;
       my ($name_1, $ip_1) = split /,/;
          my $xml = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'template.xml' );
              $xml ->set_pretty_print('indented_a');

  open ( my $input_2, '<', 'output2.csv' ) or die $!;
  while ( <$input_2> ) {
     chomp;

        my ($id, $name, $ip) = split /,/;
            $xml -> root -> set_att('name', $name);
               $xml -> get_xpath('//ipaddress',0) -> set_text($ip_1);
                  my $uri="https://hostname:9060/ers/config/networkdevice/$id";
                  my $req = HTTP::Request->new('PUT', $uri,[Accept=>'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.1+xml',
                   Content_Type=>'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.1+xml; charset=utf-8'], $xml->sprint);

                     $req->content($xml->sprint);
                     $req->authorization_basic("user", "user");

    #Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
     my $res = $ua->request($req);
    #Check the outcome of the response
    if ($res->is_success) {
        print $res->status_line, "\n";
        } else {
        print $res->status_line, "\n";
                }
       }
   }
  ```

  }

**This prints:**

```
Match found TEST_1, 10.66.12.5
UPDATE need be done for 10.66.10.4
200 OK
400 Bad Request
400 Bad Request
200 OK
200 OK
400 Bad Request
Devices should be added: TEST_3
```

Actually I was waiting for:

```
Match found TEST_1, 10.66.12.5
UPDATE need be done for 10.66.10.4
200 OK
Devices should be added: TEST_3
```

Because to do a `PUT request` with `1235,Test2,10.56.4.10`, `ipaddress` should be changed from `10.56.4.10`  to `10.56.4.14`.

But I think my problem is, that I separate my values wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $id, $first{$name}, $second{$name} = split /,/;
```

Will generate:

```
Useless use of hash element in void context ....
```

Did you actually read your error messages when running your code?

Should be:

```
( my $id, $first{$name}, $second{$name} ) = split /,/;
```

Comment: It takes now the values from `output2.csv` and makes update (no changes). I need ipaddress from `output1.csv` to be change in device with `Test2 name`.
**output2.csv:**
`1234,Test1, 10.56.7.13
 1235,Test2, 10.56.4.14`