# Fastest way to replace characters in a very large data file

Tags: regex, powershell, perl, large-data, large-files

I have a very large file (19M rows) and the data needs to be cleaned. I am using a windows 11 machine.  The data is being loaded into SQL server 19. I am currently  using a perl script to remove any commas that are between double quotes. I will post my script below.  This is taking a very long time to run. I feel like powershell would be quicker, but I can not seem to get it to run the REGEX that I need.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
 

my $SRC = $ARGV[0];
my $DES = $ARGV[1];
open(SRC,'<',$SRC) or die $!;
open(DES,'>',$DES) or die $!;

my $n_fields = "";
while (<>) {
    s/\s+$//;
    if (/^\#/) { # header line
        my @t = split(/,/);
        $n_fields = scalar(@t); # total number of fields
    } else { # actual data
        my $n_commas = $_ =~s/,/,/g; # total number of commas
        foreach my $i (0 .. $n_commas - $n_fields) { # iterate ($n_commas - $n_fields + 1) times
            s/(\"[^",]+),([^"]+\")/$1\"$2/g; # single replacement per previous answers
        }
        s/\"//g; # removal of double quotes (if you want)
    }
    print DES "$_\n";
}

close (DES);
close (SRC);
```

The code I provided above works, but is very very slow. Looking for a quicker way to process the data.  Than you in advance.

Comment: Can the header line appear anywhere else than the very 1st line in the file?

Comment: `tr/,//` is faster than `s/,/,/g` to count commas.

Comment: For single replacement, `/g` is not needed.

Comment: I can delete the header row if that helps. It can not be anyplace else, but it is not needed.

Comment: the /g works as it is now

Comment: so just change the s to a tr?

Comment: Would be helpful to know what your code is doing. Using PowerShell may be faster, but wouldn't know where to begin if we don't understand what we're looking at.

Comment: The check for the header runs for every line. Processing the first line separately would speed up the script. `/g` works, but without it the script could run faster (not tested). You change `s/,/,/g` to `tr/,//` as I showed above.

Comment: Can you state in plain words what you want to do?  The question says "_remove any commas that are between double quotes_" but then what is that counting of commas vs fields and why is there a loop?  Do you really simply want to remove commas between double quotes?   Then quotes themselves need be removed as well?  Trailing spaces, too?  Can we have a short sample of typical input?

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would obviously lead to processing times that are even within an order of magnitude of the time needed for I/O on a large file. Try timing how long it takes to just do a straight copy of the file - no matter how well your processing is optimized, you'll never get this to be faster than copying the file without modification.

Comment: Note that, as a rule of thumb, PowerShell is _slow_ for processing large text files as plain text; it trades speed for high-level, OO functionality.

Comment: Ok, you are using the diamond operator `<>` in your while loop when you should be using `<SRC>`, and you are using arguments when calling the program, so it will try to read the files in `@ARGV`, first the input file, then the output file, all the while adding to the output file. You may have created an infinite loop. How large does your output file become if you wait a while?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take the task to be: remove commas under quotes, and remove quotes as well. (So clean up extra commas and remove quotes from a CSV file.)

For starters here is some streamlined regex-based code that does that. I'd expect this to be considerably faster than the OP code.  Please provide a sample input (and/or time this code) for improvements.  Please note the assumptions clearly taken.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 file\n";

open my $fh, $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my $header = <$fh>;

if ($header !~ /^#/) {  # not header but data! Process
    print $header =~ s{"[^"]+"}{ $& =~ tr/,"//dr }ger;  #" stop bad syntax hilite
}

while (<$fh>) {
    print s{"[^"]+"}{ $& =~ tr/,"//dr }ger;  #"
}
```

Using a library (like [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544851/4653379) for an example) is always recommended but may not be faster in this case.   (Need a realistic sample to benchmark this against a CSV library.)<sup>†</sup>

---

<sup>†</sup> While waiting for a realistic sample here is a benchmark.

I make an input file by repeating 1,000 times, and shuffling, lines:

```
have,"text, and, commas","and more, commas",end
so,"no stuff with commas","yes remove, commas",done
```

Then run on it a program

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

#use Test::More qw(no_plan);  # uncomment to run a test below
use Text::CSV; 
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 file\n";

my $runfor = shift // 3;

sub by_lib {
    my ($csv, $fh) = @_;
    my @lines;

    my @headers = @{ $csv->getline($fh) };
    if ($headers[0] !~ /^#/) { # not headers! data
        tr/,//d for @$row; 
        push @lines, join ',', @$row;
    }

    while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {  #
        tr/,//d for @$row;
        push @lines, join ',', @$row;
    }

    seek $fh, 0, 0;  # return filehandle to beginning for the next run
    return \@lines;
}

sub by_regex {
    my ($fh) = @_;    
    my @lines;

    my $header = <$fh>;
    if ($header !~ /^#/) { # not actually a header but data!
        push @lines, $header =~ s{"([^"]+)"}{ $1 =~ tr/,//dr }ger; #"
    }

    while (<$fh>) {
        push @lines, s{"([^"]+)"}{ $1 =~ tr/,//dr }ger;  #"
    }

    seek $fh, 0, 0;  # return filehandle to beginning for the next run

    chomp @lines;
    return \@lines;
};    



my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1, allow_whitespace => 1 } ) 
    or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag (); 

open my $fh, $file or die $!;

# Check, at least once for every change in code
#is_deeply( by_regex($fh),  by_lib($csv, $fh), 'Cleaned up CSV' ); 

cmpthese( -$runfor, {
    by_regex => sub { by_regex($fh) },
    by_lib   => sub { by_lib($csv, $fh) },
});
```

If your input plays loose with quotes, having fields like `some "then quoted" more` instead of the whole field being quoted, then use [allow_loose_quotes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#allow_loose_quotes) attribute with the library.

Running `program.pl input.csv 30` (each test for 30 seconds) on an old laptop with v5.16 I get

```
          Rate   by_lib by_regex
by_lib   130/s       --     -14%
by_regex 152/s      17%       --
```

(Practically the same on a server with 5.36.0, with rates roughly twice as large.)

If this holds in your case, and the regex cannot be substantially improved, then I'd *strongly* recommend using the code with the CSV library instead. The library's correctness and ability to handle a range of unexpected/bad CSV properties is far more worth than 20-ish percent of speed improvement.

Then instead of collecting lines in an array (`push @lines, join ',', @$row;`), done above for benchmarking, print them as they come (`say join ',', @$row;`), at least for very large files.

Comment: Updated benchmark on a clean and quiet system (not much change, 22% -> 17%)

Comment: The more likely scenario is that he has created an infinite loop by using the diamond operator by mistake.

Comment: @TLP Well, possible; that in/out file management is certainly off, like you say.  But either way, their processing is much too complicated and I wanted to post some streamlined code, which is probably considerably faster (than their code with input/output mangling fixed).

Comment: It was taking 45 minutes to process a 7 gig file (19M rows). Now its done in under 5. This was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have created an endless loop, writing to a file while reading it.

```perl
my $SRC = $ARGV[0];     # files in your @ARGV will be read by <> diamond operator
my $DES = $ARGV[1];
....
while (<>) {            # should be <SRC>, but is <>
....
    print DES "$_\n";   # adding lines to your output file while reading it with <>
```

Change `while (<>)` to `while (<SRC>)` and see what that does. And probably check the file size of your output file to confirm a huge file indicating an endless loop.